# Get Current Active View in a Region without using RegionNavigationJournal

Tags: wpf, prism

How do I get the currently active view showed on a region managed by PrismLibrary? Preferably without using the IRegionNavigationJournal

```cs
_regionManager.Regions["Body"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that required IRegionNavigationJournal

```cs
regionManager.Regions["Body"].NavigationService.Journal.CurrentEntry.Uri.OriginalString;
```